# I want all phone numbers and their respective Bidding Amount from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

**How to fetch this Data**

I only want number and their respective bidding amount.

This id my code:

```
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.child(statusScreenLoaders.get(position).getItemName()).getValue();
                        for ( String key : map.keySet() ) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: "+key);


                        }
                            for (Object value:map.values()){

                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " +value);
                        }
```

[image]

Comment: which number exactly? 7376...?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes that is the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to get the number:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("KitKat");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                               String key = ds.getKey();
                            }
                     }
```

`String key = ds.getKey();` will return then number that you want. You can then create another reference inside the for loop to get the data of the binding amount:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("KitKat");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                               String key = ds.getKey();
                               DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("KitKat").child(key);
                               reference.child("BiddingAmount").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                 @Override
                             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    String num = dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue(String.class);
                                   }
                            }
                     }
```